# SP Services not working in IE

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I have a SharePoint 2010 webpage I am building off a simple SharePoint list. The idea is have a list that automatically build the first half of sharepoint pages. The page renders fine in FF and Chrome, but doesn't in IE. It never loads the contents of the list into the desired divs. Almost like the code is not firing. THANKS FOR THE HELP!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "HomepageControl",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Item1link' /><FieldRef Name='Item2link' /><FieldRef Name='Item3link' /><FieldRef Name='Item4link' /><FieldRef Name='Item1image' /><FieldRef Name='Item2image' /><FieldRef Name='Item3image' /><FieldRef Name='Item4image' /><FieldRef Name='FeatureEnabled' /><FieldRef Name='WelcomeMessage' /><FieldRef Name='PageHeading' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var newhtml = "<div id='contentheaderbar'>" + $(this).attr("ows_PageHeading") + "</div>" + "<div id='dasheddividerbin'><img width='2' height='5' src='/sites/corpcomm/SiteAssets/TemplateTest/images/fill.gif' border='0'/></div>" + "<div class='whitebg' id='innercontentbin' style='text-align: right; '>" +
                        "<div id='WelcomeBin'>" + $(this).attr("ows_WelcomeMessage") + "</div>" + "<div id='FeaturedBin'><h2>Featured Links:</h2><ul>" + "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item1link") + "' target='_blank'><img width='166' height='106' src='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item1image") + "' border='0'/></a></li>" + "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item2link") + "' target='_blank'><img width='166' height='106' src='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item2image") + "' border='0'/></a></li>" + "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item3link") + "' target='_blank'><img width='166' height='106' src='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item3image") + "' border='0'/></a></li>" + "<li><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item4link") + "' target='_blank'><img width='166' height='106' src='" + $(this).attr("ows_Item4image") + "' border='0'/></a></li>" + "</ul><div class='clear'></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div></div>" + "<div id='dasheddividerbin'><img width='2' height='5' src='/sites/corpcomm/SiteAssets/TemplateTest/images/fill.gif' border='0'></div>"
                    $('#maindiv').append(newhtml);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>  
<div id="maindiv"></div>
```

Comment: check debugger console for errors

Comment: @Huangism I dont have anything in the debug for the the page. It is embedded on a larger sharepoint page though. If the page loads jquery 1.6 in the header and then i call 1.10 in this piece is that an issue?

Comment: Are saying you have two versions of jQuery being loaded? If so, then you need to read up on jQuery's noConflict and understand the script loading sequence so that your jQuery plugins (aka: SPServices) are added to the expected version.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you try to debug with some `alert()` into your code to find what is triggered in IE or what is not? Also you say "IE" but not the version. IE6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ? All of them?

Comment: What browser mode is IE using? Is it displaying the page in quirks mode? If so, then that is probably the issue.

Comment: I ripped everything apart and re-built this and it worked fine. I must have some syntax error in the image insertions area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ripped everything apart and re-built this and it worked fine. I must have some syntax error in the image insertions area. Thanks!